# Product decomposition of a nonnegative matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-matrices

Suppose $A\neq 0$ is a nonnegative matrix which can be decomposed as $BC$ with $B\neq 0$ nonnegative and $C$ orthogonal. Then, is $C$ also nonnegative?

I think yes. The case when $B$ is invertible is trivial. But, if $B$ is not invertible, it does not seem obvious. Any hints? Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. For example, if $A = B = 0$, then $C$ can be anything.

Comment: ok. Suppose I make the assumption that $A\neq 0$ and $B\neq 0$, then? edited the post

Comment: Then you can still do $A' \oplus 0 = (B' \oplus 0)(C' \oplus D)$ and $D$ can be anything.